# Restrict Azure CDN downloads to Azure Active Directory Clients

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, cdn, azure-cdn

We want to restrict file downloads from Azure CDN to instances of a given tool. These tools already have an ADFS client which is currently used to get a bearer token to authenticate the client with an API housed in DataPower. I want to create an Azure AD group, assign the clients client-ids/secrets within this group, and restrict READ access to CDN files to this group so that they can get a bearer token and access the resource.

Is there a pre-existing pattern to restrict Read access in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Your application can have authorization decision to provide read access to CDN resources.

Kindly go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes) to get detailed explanation.